# Bind a Grid Row Height to a Dependency Property of User Control

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding

I think I'm missing something here, and it's probably something simple - but here is my issue.

I have created a WPF UserControl which consists of a multi-row grid, each row containing a button.  On this UserControl, I have implemented a number of dependency properties, the intent of which is to control the row height of the corresponding button.  **By setting the value to `true`, the intent is that the row shows up (height 70* instead of 0); however, currently the row height is not getting reset to the proper value of 70***.  Any idea what I did wrong? I can't figure out how to debug the ValueConverter, as a breakpoint set in it is never hit. Probably the binding logic is incorrect, but I don't know what else to put in it.

```
public bool ShowCancelButton
{
   get { return (bool)GetValue(ShowCancelButtonProperty); }
   set { SetValue(ShowCancelButtonProperty, value); }
}

// Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for ShowCancelButton.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
public static readonly DependencyProperty ShowCancelButtonProperty =
   DependencyProperty.Register("ShowCancelButton", typeof(bool), typeof(myClass), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(false, FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.AffectsRender));
```

So, to go from `bool` to `GridLength`, I have an `IValueConverter`:

```
public class RowVisibilityConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        //This should return a grid row height value of either 0 (for hidden) or 70* (for visible)
        if (bool.Parse(value.ToString()))
            return new GridLength(70, GridUnitType.Star);

        return 0;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

And, in the XAML, I'm trying to do the binding:

```
<RowDefinition Height="{Binding ElementName=ShowCancelButton, Converter={StaticResource RowVisibilityConverter}}"/>
```

Comment: Have you setted the DataContext on the UserControl somewhere for this to work?

Comment: I don't see a path in that binding. ShowCancelButton is a property -- ElementName should be the name of the element it belongs to. ShowCancelButton would be the Path, not the ElementName.

Comment: There must be (or ought to be) some named instance of your UserControl in the XAML where you have that binding. Say the instance had x:Name="Foo"; then it'd be `{Binding ShowCancelButton, ElementName=Foo}`

Comment: @EdPlunkett your solution works also - I can upvote if you post as an answer. I just had to specify `ElementName` properly (the code in the question was after I changed it as part of troubleshooting, I did not expect it to work as-written, but it didn't work no matter what I did)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to do this entirely in xaml, from what I understood you are doing.

Just name the root of your usercontrol and bind with the ElementName of that and the path of your DependencyProperty.

Toggling of the DependencyProperty is then up to you to decide if it is a togglebutton or mouse/keyboard event.

```
<UserControl x:Name="MyGridControlRoot" x:Class="WpfApplication2.MyGridControl"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             mc:Ignorable="d">

    <UserControl.Resources>
        <Style x:Key="RowStyle" TargetType="{x:Type RowDefinition}">
            <Setter Property="Height" Value="0"/>
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ElementName=MyGridControlRoot, Path=ShowCancelButton}" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="Height" Value="70*"/>
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </UserControl.Resources>

    <StackPanel>
        <Grid>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Style="{StaticResource RowStyle}"/>
                <RowDefinition Style="{StaticResource RowStyle}"/>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>

            <Grid Grid.Row="0">
                <Button/>
            </Grid>
            <Grid Grid.Row="1">
                <Button/>
            </Grid>
        </Grid>

        <ToggleButton x:Name="ToggleHeightButton" IsChecked="{Binding ElementName=MyGridControlRoot, Path=ShowCancelButton}"/>
    </StackPanel>

</UserControl>
```

Answer (score 1):

Change your `Binding` as following:

```
<RowDefinition Height="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}},Path=ShowCancelButton, Converter={StaticResource RowVisibilityConverter}}"/>
```

Above `expression` is on the basis of information you have given, `UserControl` has `DependencyProperty` named `ShowCancelButton`. So you need to do Ancestor Binding If you want to access a Parent's property from `Child Elements`.

***PS:*** Change `UserControl` with your actual type of parent `Control`.

Comment: This gave me an error that it couldn't find the name of the property (ShowCancelButton), even though I had it typed correctly and was referencing my user control class type.

Comment: @theMayer sorry i wrote this syntax so missed 1  '}'. please try now :)

Comment: Yes, this works now.  You know, while I like the flexibility of XAML, there should not be 10 different ways to achieve the exact same behavior.

Comment: @theMayer there are some limitations in XAML(triggers), on the other hand converts gives you flexibility to write down a larger logic for an output. so their target uses are not exactly the same.